# New OSX User: Opening up a new terminal window in current space(?)

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm just meddling with OSX after a few years on Linux. There's a lot that I'm liking, but one thing that's slowing me down is that if I run the 'terminal' command via shortcut/spotlight/quicksilver, it whisks me off to any existing terminal in whatever space already has a terminal instance open.

I regularly like to pop up a terminal, run a quick command and then close it again, all the while staying in whatever desktop space I happen to be on.

...So, how do I do that on Mac?

Cheers...

Comment: I'm quite new to SO, but I believe this should be under http://superuser.com

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to `System Preferences -> Exposé & Spaces -> Spaces` and check `When switching to an application, switch to...`

Comment: In Mavericks (OSX 10.9), this has moved to Mission Control (hooray for search in System Preferences).  I unchecked 'When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application' to get the desired behavior.  Awesome tip, thanks.

Comment: It seems that when I now try to open a terminal/safari window in a blank space nothing happens when this is unchecked.

Comment: @blitzen Did you ever figure this out? Just discovered this setting and I'm having the same issue on OSX 10.11.6

Answer (score 1):

Download this tool called [Visor](http://visor.binaryage.com/)

It lets you quickly get a tabbed drop down terminal using a hotkey like Ctrl-`.

Insanely convenient for working in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tool: https://github.com/nmadhok/OpenInTerminal

This is a really handy tool for programmers on Mac as it lets you open the folder directly in Terminal. You can select multiple folders to open them in multiple terminal windows. You can also select files to open the parent directory in Terminal. This application works with Finder as well as without Finder which is a plus!